# Скролл JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал навбар, которой при прокрутке вниз пропадает, при прокрутке вверх появляется.
Все работает, как и задумывалось, но при тестировании на устройствах iphone, возникает следующая **проблема:**

**Если скроллить вверх он появляется, все работает, но при достижении верха страницы он опять пропадает, хотя должен фиксироваться. После перезагрузки страницы, он опять появляется**

На остальных устройствах, работает, как положено все.

**код JS:**

```
<script>
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-70px";
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
</script>
```

**Как исправить данную проблему?**

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что на устройствах ios, когда вы достигаете верха страницы, скролл можно продолжить еще на несколько условных em. Конечно после того, как вы отпустите скролл, страница вернётся в исходное положение автоматически, в связи с чем условие продолжить выполняться, без учёта этого момента.

**КОД С РЕШЕНИЕМ:**

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-70px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    if (scrollTop == currentScrollPos) {
        document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
    }
}
```